# Use of temporary variable changes formatted output

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

While maintaining some code, I came across this statement:

```
 sActDiln := Format('%.*f',[tdDigits.ndd, Fields[itd].AsFloat * rfc / 100]);
```

In order to see what was going on, I added a temporary variable (actDiln) of type DOUBLE and altered the code as follows:

```
 actDiln := Fields[itd].AsFloat * rfc / 100;
 sActDiln := Format('%.*f',[tdDigits.ndd, actDiln]);
```

When "Fields[itd].AsString" is 35 and "rfc" is 109, the computed value changed from 38.15 to 38.14999999.  When the number of decimal digits was 1, this then changed the computed value from 38.2 to 38.1.  And this caused other problems.

I did not anticipate that using this temporary variable would cause such problems.  Can anyone explain what is going on here?  And what is best practice in the future to avoid this?

This demonstrates the problem:

```
Uses DB, DBISAMTb;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
   var
      t : TDBISAMTable;
      actDiln, rfc : double;
      actDilnE : extended;
      sActDiln1, sActDiln2, sActDiln3 : string;
   begin
   t := TDBISAMTable.Create(Application);

   WITH t DO BEGIN
      TableName := 'xxx';
      DataBaseName := 'Study';

      Active := False;
      Exclusive := False;
      IF Exists THEN DeleteTable;

      WITH FieldDefs DO BEGIN
         Clear;
         Add('fld', ftString, 10, False);
         END;
      WITH IndexDefs DO BEGIN
         Clear;
         END;
      CreateTable;
      Exclusive := True; //<<<<<<<<<<<<<
      IndexName := '';
      Open;
      Append;
      FieldByName('fld').AsString := '35';
      Post;

      rfc := 109;

      actDiln := Fields[0].AsFloat * rfc / 100;
      sActDiln1 := Format('%.*f',[1, Fields[0].AsFloat * rfc / 100]);
      sActDiln2 := Format('%.*f',[1, actDiln]);
      actDilnE := Fields[0].AsFloat * rfc / 100;
      sActDiln3 := Format('%.*f',[1, actDilnE]);
      ShowMessage(sActDiln1 + ' vs ' + sActDiln2 + ' vs ' + sActDiln3);
      end;
   end;
```

Comment: What database are you using? What is the actual declared type of the `Fields[itd]` column? I can't reproduce this issue using either Double or Extended values, for any value of `ndd`.

Comment: I could answer this question if only you could provide an SSCCE.

Comment: DBISAM 4.  I have added some working code in my original problem description.  That said, I believe that Eugene hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Eugene is correct. Floating-point math and values are fickle like this. If you want more details, check out [this blog post](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/03/22/intermediate-floating-point-precision/) to see how much "fun" this causes in C/C++ .

Comment: You could easily have given us an SSCCW without any DB code in a 20 line program. Learning to do that will be of great benefit to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inline floating-point calculations are usually of Extended type. Check the behavior when your intermediate variable is Extended too.